# Negative/dark images, source file looks good. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using UIImageView+AFNetworking to download some images from amazon s3.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];
[imview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string] placeholderImage:nil];
```

The source file looks good, when I consult it directly in amazon, the image displays just fine. But when I download it to the simulator/phone it appears like negative/dark.

This just happens to 8 images out of 1100. All are the same size, same white background.

Any ideas ?

Link to one of the images that display negative: [image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fotostaxistas/b3478810f424f23b2abb52bf616747c91b0118e004df6cb22678663c23c53bdb.jpg)

link to one of the images that display normally: [image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fotostaxistas/b18fcb52045a9dc2cb3b7abbd6952ebff00383a08eb9591dcb7615fa96e93ec4.jpg)

Comment: I assume this is repeatable, that it's always the same eight images that have this problem? Is it possible to share one of the offending images with us?

Comment: thanks @Rob , I'll put the link in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fascinating little `UIImage+AFNetworking` bug. The problem is buried somewhere in the `AFInflatedImageFromResponseWithDataAtScale` function.

It appears you can get around this problem by turning off `automaticallyInflatesResponseImage`, e.g.:

```
AFImageResponseSerializer *serializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
serializer.automaticallyInflatesResponseImage = NO;
[self.imageView setImageResponseSerializer:serializer];
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Comment: I'll try this right away, I thought it had something to do with AF cause I tried loading it with UIImage and NSData and it looks better. still a little bit dark though. thanks a lot @Rob

Comment: works great. But another bug came up. I'm using `UIImage+Alpha` and `Uiimage+RoundedImage` to make images round. Works perfect untill I try to round an image that has the `automaticallyInflatesResponseImage` set to `NO`. When I do this, the image goes completely blank.

Comment: @RoHiguera Does this new problem manifest itself just with these eight images, or is that true with all of them. I.e. is this new problem another manifestation of problems arising from the atypical colorspace of these particular images, or is it a function of the `automaticallyInflatesResponseImage` setting. In my experience, many third-party routines do not gracefully handle the atypical options in images (and thus I'd guess this new problem is a function of the images, not the `automaticallyInflatesResponseImage` setting). Can you share links to these two categories you're using?

Comment: @RoHiguera In terms of the image rendition being so dark (and over saturated, too much contrast, etc.), these are probably all by-products of a CMYK JPEG converting its colorspace for the device.

Comment: it only happens with these eight images. I think I'll just mask the UIImageView to display in a circle. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: FYI, I submitted an "[issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1706)" on the AFNetworking GitHub site.